# my hadoop2.6.5 HA ,when import data from mysql ,run error java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

In my Hadoop2.6.5  HA ,when I use sqoop 1.4.6 to import data from mysql data ,I get following error.

OS:Centos6.5bit

Does anyone face same proble?
if anywhere i miss it ??

```
[hadoop@dns app]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive --username hive --password hive --table DBS --m 1 --target-dir /user/test3
Warning: /home/hadoop/app/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/hadoop/app/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
17/09/01 16:54:11 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `DBS` AS t LIMIT 1
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `DBS` AS t LIMIT 1
17/09/01 16:54:11 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /home/hadoop/app/hadoop
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/53650552d9b1969139bf57841c0c9aa1/DBS.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/09/01 16:54:14 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/53650552d9b1969139bf57841c0c9aa1/DBS.jar
17/09/01 16:54:14 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.
17/09/01 16:54:14 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct
17/09/01 16:54:14 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
17/09/01 16:54:14 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)
17/09/01 16:54:14 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of DBS
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/app/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/app/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/09/01 16:54:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/09/01 16:54:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
17/09/01 16:54:14 WARN fs.FileSystem: "cluster1" is a deprecated filesystem name. Use "hdfs://cluster1/" instead.
17/09/01 16:54:20 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
17/09/01 16:54:20 WARN fs.FileSystem: "cluster1" is a deprecated filesystem name. Use "hdfs://cluster1/" instead.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractMapDecorator.containsKey(AbstractMapDecorator.java:83)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.isDeprecated(Configuration.java:558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.handleDeprecation(Configuration.java:605)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:444)
[hadoop@dns app]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StackOverFlowError` occurred because java callstack has grown and there is not more memory in running JVM to accomodate more callstack details.

Please see Java error stack  carefully and note
- There are following two functions

```
public static FileContext getFileContext(final URI defaultFsUri, final Configuration aConf)
public static FileContext getFileContext(final Configuration aConf)
```

Under certain conditions 1st getFileContext calls second getFileContext and second getFileContext calls first getFileContext. That means its recursive call.

In your case, the `core-site.xml` must contain property `fs.defaultFS` with value `cluster1`. Instead it should be `hdfs://cluster1`. Recursive calls will go away if you set `fs.defaultFS` to proper URL `hdfs://cluster1`.

Comment: thanks ,when i change fs.defaultFS  with value hdfs://cluster1  ,The problem has been settled

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the core-site.xml must contain property fs.defaultFS with value cluster1. Instead it should be hdfs://cluster1. Recursive calls will go away if you set fs.defaultFS to proper URL hdfs://cluster1.